# How do I run a function at a specific time - even when the app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift, background-task

I am creating an app that requires a function to run at a specific time. The function will return a value which will be stored in a database. I have tried using Background Tasks but am unsure if this will do the job. This function needs to run when the app is closed too.

Would it be done using BackgroundTasks & Timer? How do pedometer apps write data to the database without you having to launch the app (this is the type of thing I want to achieve)?

How can this be done?

Comment: What platform are you asking about? iOS? macOS?

Comment: iOS. The code needs to run when the app is terminated

Comment: You should add the iOS tag to your question. People use tags to search SO, and it is quite painful to have to wade through the comments to figure out the context of a question. (When asking a question, stop and think: "Somebody reading this question knows absolutely nothing about my situation. Have I given a complete description of my problem?" Assume you have not, and think about details you have missed.) And when people ask clarifying questions, add the information TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION. Remember that questions are useful to future SO users too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Period. Apple explicitly prevents third party apps from doing this. (Apple's apps can do things ours cannot.)

The closest you can get is setting up a local notification that pops up an alert with a button for the user to launch your app.

If you have a jailbroken app you could almost certainly install a Unix Chron job, but we don't have that access to nornal iOS devices.

Comment: Ah I see. Would silent push notifications enable the app to be able to run a function? I'm trying to understand how some apps work. I have an app that tracks my steps, I never open it but when I hit my target, it sends me a notification to say "congratulations". The app also converts the steps into points and adds them to my total. How do you think they do that?

Comment: Certain classes of apps like exercise apps, turn-by-turn navigation apps, and music apps, are granted special permission to do extra things. I suspect the health framework has hooks for exercise apps that let them launch based on your activities, but I haven't looked at it in detail.

Comment: (turn by-turn navigation apps and streaming audio apps are able to run continuously from the background, assuming the user authorizes it. VoIP apps also used to, but I'm not sure if that's still the case.)

Comment: Silent push notifications might let you run briefly from the background at designated times. I haven't looked at that in a while.  I suggest you read Apple's docs on the subject, and self-answer your question if you find a solution.